# Average of top 5 value in a table for a given group by

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've got a redshift table with many columns. Id like to be able in a single query to get the avg value of a given column and the average value of the top 5 values for a given group by clause

Here is what I tried to do

```
SELECT main.group_value
       , count(main.group_value)
       , avg(main.value) as avg_value
       , (SELECT avg(sub_calc) from (
             SELECT sub.physical_idx_1 as sub_psv99
                    , rank() over (order by sub.psv99 desc) as rank 
             FROM phys_red_physical_v0_0 as sub 
             WHERE sub.group_value=main.group_value
         ) WHERE rank <=5
       ) as avg_top5_value
FROM my_table as main
GROUP BY main.group_value;
```

I was met with this error message:

```
ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet
```

What other way can I achieve what I am trying to do without having to do two queries ?

EDIT: As suggested in comments here is an example using Cars:

Data:

```
manufacturer | model | price
Citroen        C1      1
Citroen        C2      2
Citroen        C3      3
Citroen        C4      4
Citroen        C5      5
Citroen        C6      6
Ford           F1      7
Ford           F2      8
Ford           F3      9
Ford           F4      10
Ford           F5      11
Ford           F6      12 
Ford           F6      19 
GenMotor       G1      20
GenMotor       G3      25
GenMotor       G4      22
```

Expected Output:

```
manufacturer | average_price | average_top_5_price
Citroen        3.5             4.0
Ford           10.85           12.2
GenMotor       22.33           22.33
```

Comment: Are you saying you have a table of car with various prices and models and you want  A) the average price across all cars and B) the average price of the top 5 cars and you want all of this displayed on one line?

Comment: almost, I want what you describe but I want one line per manufacturer

Comment: I suspect if you draw a table of an example starting data and example table of what the result should look like using an example like cars you'll get an answer faster since we won't have to decompose your query and can just work with the start and desire end.

Comment: Please Edit your Question and include some **sample data in the table** together with **the output you would want from that sample data**.

Comment: I've added an example to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result without using a correlated subquery, you can use a combination of window functions and aggregation. Here's how you can rewrite your query:

```sql
SELECT
    main.manufacturer,
    AVG(main.price) AS average_price,
    AVG(CASE WHEN rank <= 5 THEN main.price END) AS average_top_5_price
FROM (
    SELECT
        manufacturer,
        price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY manufacturer ORDER BY price DESC) AS rank
    FROM
        your_table
) main
GROUP BY
    main.manufacturer;
```

This query first assigns a row number to each row within its manufacturer group based on the price in descending order. Then, it calculates the average price and the average of the top 5 prices within each manufacturer group. Finally, it groups the results by the manufacturer.

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question, now I'll see how my ORM will handle doing this