# Average of top 5 value in a model

Tags: sql, django, django-models, amazon-redshift

I've got a django model with a lot of fields. I'm trying in a single query to get the avg value of a given field and the average value of the top 5 values of that same field (from my other question regarding pure SQL: [Average of top 5 value in a table for a given group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77906902/average-of-top-5-value-in-a-table-for-a-given-group-by)). Not that it should matters but: my database is redshift.

I've found two different ways to achieve this in SQL, but I'm having trouble implementing those queries using django ORM

Here is an example of what I want to do using Cars:

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField()
    model = models.CharField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Data:

```
manufacturer | model | price
Citroen        C1      1
Citroen        C2      2
Citroen        C3      3
Citroen        C4      4
Citroen        C5      5
Citroen        C6      6
Ford           F1      7
Ford           F2      8
Ford           F3      9
Ford           F4      10
Ford           F5      11
Ford           F6      12 
Ford           F6      19 
GenMotor       G1      20
GenMotor       G3      25
GenMotor       G4      22
```

Expected Output:

```
manufacturer | average_price | average_top_5_price
Citroen        3.5             4.0
Ford           10.85           12.2
GenMotor       22.33           22.33
```

Here are two pure SQL queries achieving the desired effect:

```
SELECT
    main.manufacturer,
    AVG(main.price) AS average_price,
    AVG(CASE WHEN rank <= 5 THEN main.price END) AS average_top_5_price
FROM (
    SELECT
        manufacturer,
        price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY manufacturer ORDER BY price DESC) AS rank
    FROM
        cars
) main
GROUP BY
    main.manufacturer;
```

And the second way of doing it:

```
SELECT A.manufacturer, A.avg_price, B.top5_price
FROM (
    SELECT manufacturer, AVG(price) as avg_price
    FROM cars
    GROUP BY manufacturer
) A
JOIN (
    SELECT manufacturer, AVG(psv_99) as top5_price
    FROM (
        SELECT manufacturer, price, RANK()
        OVER (PARTITION BY manufacturer ORDER BY price DESC, id)
        FROM cars
    )
    WHERE rank <= 5
    GROUP BY manufacturer
) B
ON A.manufacturer = B.manufacturer
ORDER BY manufacturer
```

So far I haven't manage to implement either of those queries using django ORM, for the first one I can't find a way to have django do a "select from subquery" for the second one I can't find a good way to force django to "join two subquery"

PS: Keep in mind that I have reduced my table to three fields to simplify solving that particular problem, but I have ~100 column in my real table on which I'm making different calculation in the same queries.

Comment: Re *"not that it should matter but my database is..."*: it's actually very important. I wanted to suggest [`django-cte`](https://dimagi.github.io/django-cte/) that solves exactly your problem, but it supports only Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `values` and `annotate` to `group by` manufacturer then calculate the group's average with `Avg`.

The `average_price` is quite easy to calculate:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models.functions import Round

averages =
Car.objects.values("manufacturer").annotate(average_price=Round(Avg("price"), precision=2))
```

But to calculate the top five in each group, it gets a little complicated (I think). For that, you need a `Subquery`. So, the full code would be:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Avg, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Round

group_top_5 = Car.objects.filter(manufacturer=OuterRef("manufacturer")).order_by("-price")[:5].values("price")

query_filter = Q(price__in=group_top_5)
averages = (
Car.objects.values("manufacturer")
.annotate(
average_price=Round(Avg("price"), precision=2), 
average_top_5_price=Round(Avg("price", filter=query_filter), precision=2))

)
```

This should give you:

```
{'manufacturer': 'Citroen', 'average_price': 3.5, 'average_top_5_price': 4.0}
{'manufacturer': 'Ford', 'average_price': 10.86, 'average_top_5_price': 12.2}
{'manufacturer': 'GenMotor', 'average_price': 22.33, 'average_top_5_price': 22.33}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, this solution is more or less my first attempt, but unfortunately , the database doesn't support "This type of correlated subquery pattern", the problem is django generate a subquery in a "case when" which the database is not happy about. See my original question in pure SQL for the detail

Comment: That's really unfortunate.

Comment: I'm thinking I probably should write a bug report on that since django should not generate an invalid SQL

Answer (score 0):

The conditional aggregation query would have been the best but unfortunately I could not translate it to Django. Here is my attempt at conversion:

```py
from carsdemo.models import Cars
from django.db.models import Avg, F, RowRange, Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber

result = (
    Cars.objects.values("manufacturer")
    .annotate(
        average_price=Window(
            expression=Avg("price"),
            partition_by=F("manufacturer"),
        ),
        average_top_5_price=Window(
            expression=Avg("price"),
            partition_by=F("manufacturer"),
            order_by=F("price").desc(),
            frame=RowRange(start=0, end=4),
        ),
        rn=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by=F("manufacturer"),
            order_by=F("price").desc(),
        ),
    )
    .filter(rn=1)
)
```

It produces the following query (on SQL Server):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        carsdemo_cars.manufacturer AS Col1,
        AVG(carsdemo_cars.price) OVER (PARTITION BY carsdemo_cars.manufacturer ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS average_price,
        AVG(carsdemo_cars.price) OVER (PARTITION BY carsdemo_cars.manufacturer ORDER BY carsdemo_cars.price DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 4 FOLLOWING) AS average_top_5_price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY carsdemo_cars.manufacturer ORDER BY carsdemo_cars.price DESC) AS rn
    FROM carsdemo_cars
) qualify
WHERE rn = 1
```

And the result:

```
<QuerySet [
{'manufacturer': 'Citroen', 'average_price': 3.5, 'average_top_5_price': 4.0, 'rn': 1},
{'manufacturer': 'Ford', 'average_price': 10.857142857142858, 'average_top_5_price': 12.2, 'rn': 1},
{'manufacturer': 'GenMotor', 'average_price': 22.333333333333332, 'average_top_5_price': 22.333333333333332, 'rn': 1}
]>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer, unfortunately my DBMS doesn't seem to support this type of queries. Like with all previous attempts, I get "NotSupportedError: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet".

Comment: Does the raw query (posted in answer) work in your RDBMS? You will have to replace TOP 1 with OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY. If so, try upgrading your libraries.

Comment: The raw query doesn't work, the error is coming directly from the database. 
But the raw queries in the question do work

Comment: See revised answer, give it a try.

Comment: Thank you again for the time invested, maybe my version of django is too old: I get django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.